# Why is underscore preferred over dash in computer science?

Tags: computer-science

It is such a pain to hold down the shift button to type underscore. Why is underscore ('_') preferred over dash ('-') in computer programming?

Edit: my questions is towards object names

Comment: Maybe because it can't be confused with the arithmetic operator `minus`?

Comment: guessing 1 means minus, the other 1 doesn't?

Comment: Just a guess, dash already has a meaning as minus. `var x = 1, y = 2, x-y = 3, z = x-y; // Wat`

Comment: @pjs, I edited my question

Comment: Object names in a language: `-` typically refers to the subtraction operator (exceptions include Lisp dialects like Scheme where `-` is a function). Production/terminal names in a formal grammar: `-` is common in dialects where blanks/spaces are not allowed in names. As the names are often typographically distinct from literal characters in non-plaintext mediums, this is enough to distinguish a `-` in a name from a `-` meant as the subtraction operator. In plaintext grammars, a `-` denoting exclusion is typically surrounded by blanks/spaces to avoid ambiguity. Those have been my experiences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dash is the minus symbol. If it were allowed to be used in variable names it would be ambiguous. Take the following code:

```
int a=10;
int b=9;
int a-b = 100;
int c = a-b;
```

What is c? Is c the value stored in the variable a-b and therefore equal 100?

Or is it a minus b, and therefore equal to 1?

Answer (score -1):

They do prefer dash in some situations :

```
int z = x-y;
```